# How to solve this javascript array delete method problem

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js

My code :

```
<html>
<body>
<p id='demo'></p>
<script>
var array=['BENZ','SKODA','BMW','MERCEDAS','VOLVO'];
delete array[2];
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = array;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I running this code...

The output [image: Comma quotation showing ...after removing the 3rd value]
Comma quotation were not deleted after execution.

Help me to solve this (or) Suggest any other ways for deleting values in the specified index in js array.

Comment: Take a look at [MDN Array splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript Why don't you take a look at this

Comment: Question needs to be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var a = ['BENZ','SKODA','BMW','MERCEDAS','VOLVO']; 
a.splice(2,1); 
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working.

Answer (score 1):

Change 
   delete array[2] 
to 
   array.splice(2,1)

Regards.

Comment: Thanks,it's working

Answer (score 1):

I would say use:

```
array.splice(index, 1);
```

the "index" parameter is an index of the element you want to remove and "1" is a number of elements you want to remove. splice() will take care of the indexes of removed/added elements for you.

If you don't know the index of the element you can try:

```
array.indexOf("BMW");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it's working

Answer (score -1):

```
var array=['BENZ','SKODA','BMW','MERCEDAS','VOLVO'];
 array.pop[2];
```

**By following you can delete the element in array .pop[]**